# What do the Ubuntu Webapps Technology offer

Tags: 12.04, webapps

I started hearing about the webapp technologies a couple of days ago and from what I have heard they look good. They will somehow integrate Ubuntu with web apps and technologies. But:

1. How will they integrate into Ubuntu?
2. How can the user use this integrated web technologies (Where would the menu options be, What options, password, user stuff do I need to add/activate/type in a form)?
3. How will the integration of this webapp technologies benefit the user?
4. What are the pros/cons in this new Ubuntu changes?
5. Will askubuntu, Ubuntu forum and other Ubuntu user sites integrate as well?

Comment: Good question. I am curious about this as well. For example, will the Google Reader Webapp allow me to save my starred items so I can access them offline?

Comment: I am interested too.  Looking at the video suggested in one of the answers, I can't see what the fuss is about.  Mostly just seems like ways to semi-automate use of web pages that I can already use. I am surely missing something :)

Comment: Going to go see if maybe it can be backported to 12.04 so I can test it. If not the virtualbox + 12.10 alpha 3 FTW and I will test it there on Sunday since my downloading speed is snail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **How will they integrate into Ubuntu?**

   Ubuntu webapps is tightly integrated to Ubuntu, ie native ubuntu unity technologies like hud , notify OSD, messaging menu , etc can be use for web apps
   [image]
   The above screen shot shows the integration of unity hud with webapps(here Gmail)
2. **How can the user use this integrated web technologies (Where would the menu options be, What options, password, user stuff do I need to add/activate/type in a form)?**
3. **How will the integration of this webapp technologies benefit the user?**

   1.Quick access for web apps

   2.User can acces webapps directly from desktop

   etc

   **Some examples of what users can do with Ubuntu WebApps:**

   1. Launch online music site Last.FM directly from the Dash and control the music from Ubuntu’s sound menu
   2. Access and launch your social media accounts (Google+, Twitter, Facebook) from the Launcher, and get native desktop notifications
   3. Quickly and seamlessly upload photos to Facebook from Shotwell
   4. Pause and play the video you are watching on Youtube
   5. See how many unread messages you have in your GMail account, in Ubuntu’s messaging indicator
4. **What are the pros/cons in this new Ubuntu changes?**
5. **Will askubuntu, Ubuntu forum and other Ubuntu user sites integrate as well?**

   Probably yes, But if you are a developer no need to wait others, here is the [API](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/javascript/index.html), start hacking ;-)

Comment: ^Not completed yet

Answer (score 0):

Here is video from Ubuntu:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7vF-AB7SF4

Hopefully it will answer your questions.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.